# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] on opportunity

Tags: opportunity, permissions, profile, master-detail

I have created an object named as `"Component"` which has `Master-Detail Relationship with Opportunity Object`. 
On Opportunity we have a button says `"Create Component"`, when user clicks on it it takes users to a new page and ask for some values and create component record. 
It was all about object structure and component creation procedure.

I am getting `"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`" when i click on `"Create Component"` and on component page when i click on `"Create"` button. 
Actually  "create Component" page has a create button and when clicks on this it creates component records.

My profile has -

```
1) Read, Create, Edit, View All on Opportunity Object 
2) Read, Create, Edit, View All on Component Object
```

> 1) This exception comes in a particular scenario when Record Creator
>   is me but Owner is some one else. If record owner and creator both is
>   me then i don't get this exception.
>
> 2) Secondly if i set Opportunity OWD setting to public Read/Write then
>   this exception doesn't come if owner is someone else as well.

I am not getting any solution and clue why i am getting this exception. Please help me out

> What are differences between owner and creator of record? What happens
>   if creator changes the owner of record? will Creator still have all the
>   rights on the records or all the rights will be transferred to Owner?

thanks in advance

Comment: whats the OWD for component?Is it controlled By Parent ?

Comment: yes - Controlled by Parent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to how Master-Detail security is setup. Detail objects inherit permissions from their Master. If the record owner does not have Edit on the Opportunity they will not be able to add any Detail records, including your `Component`. There are two things you can try:

1. Add or alter your sharing rules/profiles to give owners the permissions they need
2. Instead of using a Master-Detail, set component to use a Lookup to Opportunity. Then you do not need to worry about the permissions on the Opportunity.

**Update**

The record's creator does not have any inherit rights; it is just an audit field. Permissions are based on the Owner, Sharing Rules, and if the user in question has View All, Modify All, View All Data, or Modify All Data.

Comment: I understand if owner try to add component then he will get an exception but why i am getting this exception? i am creator of the record then i should be able to add the component i think. i can edit the opportunity without any exception but when i try to add component i get this exception

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: got you point but still i have one question that if i can edit opportunity then why i can't create component on that opportunity?

Comment: That doesn't make sense; I'll have to do more research.

Comment: one question @Mike- if i have Read, Create, Edit, View All on Opportunity Object then i can see all the opportunities but i can edit only those whose owner i am or only those whose owner comes below to me in role hierarchy. Am i correct? is there any other way that can grant me to edit the opportunities that i don't own?

Comment: Yes. At the object level you can have Modify All and at the system level you can have Modify All Data (applies to all objects.)

Comment: @Mike - If I update some detail object of Account and account owner is someone else, then how to handle such problems in Apex or how we can do error handling over here ?

Comment: @PraveshMehta - Please start a new question with the details of your problem; you'll get better responses that way.

Comment: @Mike - already done, please put your views as well http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106212/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-insufficient-access-rights-on-cro