# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Tags: apex, visualforce, security, permission-sets

I have a custom object Resource__c having master detail with Account object. I have Account1 created by User1 and if User2 goes to create resource on Account1 then below error is given :`"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []"`.

How can we handle this error before inserting or upserting in our Apex class or do exception handling for this error.

Comment: first share your code.  Second use try catch to handle exception . Third check Account OWD and profile permisssion.

Comment: Can you edit that Account record from UI if you are logged in with User2?

Comment: @Nitin - I can't edit that record, I agree that I cannot do any operation on that account but as I am having my Create new resource button in layout so I just want to know how to handle this error in my apex class so that error doesn't shown on user or some useful error should be displayed

Comment: @PraveshMehta I suggest before doing any DMl first check that current user having access to that record or not

Comment: @Ratan - it would be helpful if you can share some code. If I do such check, then sharing rules will cause any issue or not ?

Comment: I would guess that you'd need to catch the exception and then display a user-friendly message. Can you post the full text of your error? I would guess it's a `DMLException`

Comment: @PraveshMehta check my ans.. let me know if this work for you or not?

Comment: it is working fine for single record, if I want to do mass operation on accounts then SOQL governor limit may occur. Please suggest how to handle this thing for mass data operation.

Comment: @PraveshMehta are you quering inside for loop? optimize your code query outside for loop..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `userRecordAccess` object to check `CRUD` permissions..

So pass the recordId and userId.. to check that user having what type of access on that record..

you can check variables like `HasDeleteAccess`. If `HasDeleteAccess` true means user have delete access. If false then user don't have access..

Based on these accessibility perform DML..

```
List<UserRecordAccess> lstUserRecordAccess = [SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess, 
                                                     HasDeleteAccess, 
                                                     HasEditAccess,
                                                     HasReadAccess, 
                                                     HasTransferAccess 
                                                FROM UserRecordAccess 
                                               WHERE UserId = '00550000000rlrX' 
                                                 AND RecordId = '0015000000TaWdI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check accessible rights on any object by describing it as below:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
System.debug('accessible:' + accountDescribe.accessible);
```

If it is not accessible then, you can show a proper message to user.

I hope this will help.

Comment: That is related to FLS, but here problem is related to ownership of record. I am not able to modify record whose owner is someone else so I just want to handle error in my apex code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this using a dev console script I'd be using w/no issue across all sandboxes for months. The error for me was:

> EXCEPTION_THROWN [19]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
> exception on row 0; first error:
> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
> rights on cross-reference id: ...

All my script was doing was creating some new Contact records and associating them w/a specific Account (ID). Oddly after months of working this error popped up (on 2/2/23).

I couldn't find the actual issue/culprit so **to resolve I had to delete an Account record and recreate it** w/the same info. I realize this solution is messy and likely not feasible for folks struggling w/this issue in a production environment but thought I'd share that in my case, in a sandbox, recreating the record got me past this annoying error.

Answer (score -3):

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []
**This error when occurring when we are creating a record with a field relationship master details**

[image]

**THESE PERMISSIONS ARE ENABLED ON THE PARENT** 
You can also check this permissions
[image]

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
But In My Case 
 I did this thing ...
We have to allow modify all permission on the parent for example in our case it's User (Custom) Object

[image]

Comment: You are misreading this documentation. Turning on View All or Modify All is a risky choice. Please do not include your contact information in your SFSE posts.