# Sharing a record with Read/ Edit ability (Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.)

Tags: permissions, error-messages

I have two objects RequestCredentials and ProjectInformation objects.
ProjectInformation  is the master and RequestCredentials is the detail.
I faced an error when creating a record of type RequestCredential. **The error was insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.**

The error occurred when a user tried to create a RequestCredentials record on the Project information record that was created by admin.

We were able to solve the issue by setting Public Read/Write access on ProjectInformation  object OR by checking 
View All, Modify All on ProjectInformation object in User permission set.

But my lead said that this is not the correct way and asked me to search on it. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-insufficient-access-rights-on-cro?rq=1

Comment: I believe the error means you are passing an incorrect id somewhere.